# Show that $||v||^2 = ||P_0v||^2 + ||v - P_0v||^2$ for orthogoonal projection

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices, gram-schmidt

I'm working on some practice problems from Noble & Daniel's *Applied Linear Algebra (3rd)*, specifically here looking for help with question 5 from section 5.8 on pg. 232.

Suppose that $P_0$ is the orthogonal projection onto $V_0$. Show that for every **v** in *V*,

$||v||^2 = ||P_0v||^2 + ||v - P_0v||^2$

This whole section about orthogonal projections and bases has been a bit confusing for me. I'm not sure where to begin on this question. I know that $||v - P_0v||$ is orthogonal to each of the $v_i$ in **v** but and I thought that might be useful but I'm not sure how to leverage it.

Comment: Hey, question states when you use a projection if your vector does not lie completely in the projected space, norm of your vector depends on not only the  projected part but also remaining part. Regarding the proof use $||x||^2=x^T x$

Comment: I mean open up every term with it

Comment: I'm guessing $V_0$ is a subspace of $V$? I'm further guessing that $V$ is a real inner product space, possibly finite-dimensional? Also, are you aware of Pythagoras's theorem for real inner product spaces? It would be good to get some further context here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a calculation. Assume a real vector space, and note that $v=P_0v+w$ where $P_0v\perp w$  so the Pythagorean theorem applies to show that

$\|v\|^2=\|P_0v+w\|^2=\|P_0v\|^2+\|w\|^2=\|P_0v\|^2+\|v-P_0v\|^2.$

Answer (score 0):

In general, $||v+w||^2 = <v+w,v+w> = \ldots = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2 + 2<v,w>$. Now if $v \bot w$, you have that $<v,w>=0$, and you are done.